# Serve manually compressed index if client supports gzip

Tags: .htaccess, webserver, apache

I have two files: index.html and index.html.gz.

If the client supports gzip, i want to serve index.html.gz.
If the client does not, i want to serve index.html.

This should work if the visitor visits www.site.com

Really not sure how this can be done :(

EDIT: I'm trying to get it to work in .htaccess

I can do it easily with other pages by doing:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
RewriteRule ^contact\.html$ contact.gz
```

But i can't do it with the index since people don't type in www.site.com/index.html. They leave index.html out.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking... Wild guess: Gzip compression is supported by webservers (including apache), so you just need to turn it on and the client browser will take care of the rest (no need for `index.html.gz`!) - most browsers have supported gzip for years now.

Comment: I understand. But I'm compressing all my files manually since i don't want to waste cpu cycles to do it. My pages are static and never change, i dont need the server to recompress them each time a new visitor arrives. That increases Time-To-First-Byte and thus decreases load speed.

Comment: OK... Thats an interesting, if somewhat _retro_ approach. I'd suggest putting `.htaccess filetype redirects` in your question title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is reading this, I found the answer eventually.

There are various methods to do this, some webservers (like H2O) even support automatically serving the pre-zipped versions of the site if the ".gz" version of the file is present (index.html.gz) for instance.

The way i did it on Apache however was to redirect all requests for the file to the ".gz" instance using .htaccess. This is possible using RewriteRule

However, all the data would appear in the browser scrambled as the browser attempted to render GZipped data thinking it was text. I had to the use .htaccess to properly set the content-encoding header to gzip when i was sending back the gzipped version of the file. After that, everything worked perfectly.

Another word of advice, when you're gzipping files, use a batch script to gzip the file using each compression mode 1-9, you'll end up with 10 files. You will notice that the size you save going past compression mode ~5 becomes almost invisible, often less than a KB, but the CPU cycles needed to unzip this file keep growing. So find the optimal compression level for each file, don't go to 9 by default.